# Play a video from SD card and loop the video using videoView

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

My goal here is to play all the videos from a folder in SDCard for example all the videos in the download folder and play it on loop. But my problem now is when i start the app, the app always shows an error say "Can't play this video".

This is my code and i appreciate the help.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview1);
    video.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.setLooping(true);
        }
    });
    video.setVideoPath("/storage/extSdCard/Download/great.mp4");
    video.start();

}
```

Comment: make sure this file is exists or not, and did you check 
READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Comment: Check this below code :

video_view.clearFocus();
                                    Uri videoUri =Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/extSdCard/Download/great.mp4"))
                                    //set the uri of the video to be played
                                    video_view.setVideoURI(videoUri);

Comment: the file is existed for sure, and i have already write this "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>" in my Manifest.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check code may this will work for you.

```
  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
   Uri videoUri =Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/extSdCard/Download/great.mp4")) 
    //set the uri of the video to be played 
    video.setVideoURI(videoUri);
    video.start();

    video.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.setLooping(true);
        }
    });
}
```